# Distributed make for several computers on same file system

Tags: makefile, distributed

Is there a make equivalent to distribute task among several computer, all operating on the same filesystem? (without having to

example : instead of calling directly the compile command, juste raise it and then one computer available execute it ? (without rsh like dmake)

Answer (score 1):

You could try ElectricAccelerator, a distributed, high-performance reimplementation of GNU make.  It uses lightweight automatic virtualization to handle filesharing between participating computers, as well as some [clever technology](http://blog.melski.net/2011/07/05/how-electricmake-guarantees-reliable-parallel-builds/) to ensure correct parallel builds even if your dependencies are incomplete.  It's a commercial product, but you can download and try [ElectricAccelerator Huddle](http://electric-cloud.com/products/electricaccelerator/huddle), the freemium variant.

Alternatively you could try something like [distcc](https://github.com/distcc/distcc), which can distribute gcc (and gcc-like) compile commands to remote systems, in conjuction with good-old `gmake -j`.

*Disclaimer: I'm the chief architect of ElectricAccelerator*

Comment: Is there any technical documentation available how you would use the accellerator on real projects? The webinars seem mostly a lot of marketing slides aimed at management level.